# No Method Exception on a method that exists

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am attempting to locate a varible in an array, as it was taken originally from the array, but in UnityScript this is not as straighforward as I hoped.

Here is my code for finding the index:

```
function nextArea() {
    var tmp = Array.IndexOf(areas, currentArea);
    tmp++;
    currentArea = areas[tmp];
    initNewArea();
}
```

Yet whenever I run it in Unity I get this error:

```
MissingMethodException: UnityScript.Lang.Array.IndexOf
Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.MethodDispatcherFactory.ProduceExtensionDispatcher ()
Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.MethodDispatcherFactory.Create ()
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.DoCreateMethodDispatcher(System.Object target, System.Type targetType, System.String name, System.Object[] args)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.CreateMethodDispatcher (System.Object target, System.String name, System.Object[] args)
```

If you can fix it and have a github account I've opened an issue here: [GitHub](https://github.com/tomtomy8/Pixel-Crime/issues/2)

Comment: [Array](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Array.html) doesn't have an IndexOf method?

Comment: I've checked, and it does. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You are using JS i guess, and the link goes to C# (msdn link).

Comment: Its unity script which runs on the .NET framework

Comment: It does, however it appears there are differences in the API whether you use C# or JS. On the C# tab in the link I posted it says "The Array class is only available in Javascript.". Your link refers to `System.Array`, not `UnityScript.Lang.Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want like this:

```
var arr = new System.Collections.ArrayList ();

// Add elements
arr.Add ("Hello");
arr.Add("World");

Debug.Log(arr.IndexOf("World"));
```

You can also try [`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/166789/iterate-through-generic-list.html), it also contains [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Thats great, but now I'm trying to itinerate through to add the array contents to the array list: `var arr = new System.Collections.ArrayList(); for(var x = 0; x<=areas.length; x++) {arr.Add(areas[x]); } var tmp = arr.IndexOf(currentArea);`This gives me a index out of range error. What am I doing wrong now? THx in advance

Comment: Shouldn't `x<=areas.length` be `x<areas.length` ?